# Merge part of dict with duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a complete beginner with Python so please bear with me.

I have a list of dicts looking something like:

```
list = [
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "1",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "3",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "Some Place",
        "timeLeft": "15",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "Some Place",
        "timeLeft": "30",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "That other place",
        "timeLeft": "5",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
]
```

I am looking to merge those two based on "name" and "direction" to look like this:

```
new_list = [
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "1",
        "timeNext": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "Some Place",
        "timeLeft": "15",
        "timeNext": "30"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "That other place",
        "timeLeft": "5",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
]
```

How can I achieve this and also understand how it actually works?
I´ve tried alot of solutions with loops but they all end up with alot of duplicates or wrong merges.

EDIT: There are never more than one duplicate of each name and direction.

EDIT 2: This is my full method:

```
@APP.route('/api/vasttrafik/departures', methods=['POST'])
def get_departures():
    """ Departures """
    APP.logger.info('get_departures():')

    data = request.get_json()
    id_number = data['id']
    current_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    # time_span = data['']
    access_token = request.headers['access_token']

    url = 'https://api.vasttrafik.se/bin/rest.exe/v2/departureBoard?id='\
        + id_number + '&date=' + current_date + '&time=' + current_time +\
        '&format=json&timeSpan=90&maxDeparturesPerLine=2&needJourneyDetail=0'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json = req.json()
    departure_board = json['DepartureBoard']
    if 'error' in departure_board:
        raise NotFoundException('Did not find anything')
    departures = departure_board['Departure']

    def departures_model(item):

        def get_key_value(key):
            return item[key] if key in item else ''

        is_live = 'rtTime' in item
        if is_live:
            current_time = get_key_value('rtTime')
            current_date = get_key_value('rtDate')
        else:
            current_time = get_key_value('time')
            current_date = get_key_value('date')

        direction = get_key_value('direction')
        via = ''
        if 'via' in direction:
            direction, via = direction.split('via')

        time_departure = datetime.strptime(current_date + ' ' + current_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        time_now = datetime.now()
        diff = time_departure - time_now
        if time_now >= time_departure:
            minutes_left = 0
        else:
            minutes_left = math.floor(((diff).seconds) / 60)
        clock_left = item['rtTime'] if is_live else item['time']

        return dict({
            'accessibility': get_key_value('accessibility'),
            'bgColor': get_key_value('bgColor'),
            'clockLeft': clock_left,
            'clockNext': '',
            'timeLeft': int(minutes_left),
            'timeNext': '',
            'direction': direction.strip(),
            'via': 'via ' + via.strip() if via != '' else via,
            'name': get_key_value('name'),
            'sname': get_key_value('sname'),
            'type': get_key_value('type'),
            'time': get_key_value('time'),
            'date': get_key_value('date'),
            'journeyid': get_key_value('journeyid'),
            'track': get_key_value('track'),
            'fgColor': get_key_value('fgColor'),
            'isLive': is_live,
            'night': 'night' in item,
        })

    mapped_departures = list(map(departures_model, departures))

    def key(bus):
        return bus["name"], bus["direction"]

    def merge_busses(ls):
        for (name, direction), busses in groupby(ls, key):
            busses = list(busses)
            times = [bus["timeLeft"] for bus in busses]
            yield {
                **busses[0],
                "timeLeft": min(times, key=int),
                "timeNext": max(times, key=int),
            }

    merge_departures = list(merge_busses(mapped_departures))

    return jsonify({
        'departures': merge_departures,
    })
```

EDIT 3: I just found out why L3viathan & Patrick Artner's solutions does not work. They only work if the list of buses is sorted beforehand. So I guess that groupby needs dicts to be adjacent.

Comment: Will the lists always have two elements and have those keys?

Comment: Yes it will always have those keys, but it can have alot more dicts.

Comment: Provide an example with more than two dicts please (what the output looks like, then)

Comment: by what logic are you moving the 3 to the other field?

Comment: use dict update()

Comment: @PatrickArtner Its two bus departures on the same line so timeLeft is time until the bus arrives and timeNext is time until the bus after that arrives.

Comment: and if there are 4 busses in 3,5,19 minutes with same name and direction? you change from `timeNext` being a string to being a list of strings?

Comment: @PatrickArtner there are never more than two of the same line.

Comment: @L3viathan I have added more dicts to the list and expected results (new_list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution: We group the busses by their name-direction combination using `itertools.groupby`, then yield dictionaries where the `timeLeft` is the smallest number of minutes within those busses, and `timeNext` is either an empty string (if we saw just one bus) or the largest number of minutes within those busses.

```
from itertools import groupby

def key(bus):
    return bus["name"], bus["direction"]

def merge_busses(ls):
    for (name, direction), busses in groupby(sorted(ls, key=key), key):
        busses = list(busses)
        times = [bus["timeLeft"] for bus in busses]
        yield {
            **busses[0],
            "timeLeft": min(times, key=int),
            "timeNext": "" if len(times) == 1 else max(times, key=int),
        }
```

Use it like this:

```
new_list = list(merge_busses(mylist))
```

Use on your example, this produces:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "1",
        "timeNext": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "Some Place",
        "timeLeft": "15",
        "timeNext": "30"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 1",
        "direction": "That other place",
        "timeLeft": "5",
        "timeNext": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: I failed to inform you that i also have other key/values in the dicts that is needed. In your first solution I can fetch the other keys with **first[key] but with this new solution I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: bus is not defined since its scoped inside the times variable.

Comment: I get duplicates with that code now. I´ve updated my main post with the full content in the file.

Comment: I don't get duplicates with the example you provided. Give me a better example then, I don't indent to set up a Flask (?) API for this.

Comment: Of course you should not have to setup a Flask API, and I do appreciate your help. Here is the code with a real sample:
http://rextester.com/FQEEWX79332

Comment: I don't see any duplicates there either. Which two entries are duplicates?

Comment: So I _was_ right that you need it to be sorted. Fixed in edit.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this, would be to group all busses by theire `name`&&`direction`. Then merge the data, make sure the "earlier" time is in `'timeLeft'`, the later time in `'timeNext'`:

Doku: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
busses = [
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "1",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 60",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "3",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bus 21",
        "direction": "City",
        "timeLeft": "5",
        "timeNext": ""
    },
]

from itertools import groupby

def mergeBusses(listOfBussesDict):

    sortList = sorted(listOfBussesDict, key=lambda x: (x["name"],x["direction"]))
    # we use name + direction as key for the grouping
    merged = groupby(sortList, lambda x: (x["name"],x["direction"]))

    # you might consider cleaning up the keys that are used:
    # merged = groupby(sortList, lambda x: (x["name"].strip(),x["direction"].strip()))
    # if your source data is bad.

    for k,g in merged:
        sameBus = list(g)
        # now we take all times and sort them by their integer value to 
        # update the correct slots in the dictionary
        times = sorted([x["timeLeft"] for x in sameBus],key= lambda y:int(y))
        if len(times)>1: 
            # we only need to do this if the grouping has > 1 bus, in that 
            # case we use the basedata of the first bus and adjust the times
            sameBus[0]["timeLeft"] = times[0]
            sameBus[0]["timeNext"] = times[1]

        # we just yield the first bus from the group which now has correct times
        yield sameBus[0]


# need to make a list from our generator result
mergedOnes = list(mergeBusses(busses))

print(mergedOnes)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Bus 60', 'direction': 'City', 'timeLeft': '1', 'timeNext': '3'}, 
 {'name': 'Bus 21', 'direction': 'City', 'timeLeft': '5', 'timeNext': ''}]
```

Your edited example would lead to:

```
[{'name': 'Bus 60', 'direction': 'City', 'timeLeft': '1', 'timeNext': '3'},
 {'name': 'Bus 1', 'direction': 'Some Place', 'timeLeft': '15', 'timeNext': '30'}, 
 {'name': 'Bus 1', 'direction': 'That other place', 'timeLeft': '5', 'timeNext': ''}]
```

Comment: @L3viathan I dont quite get why I would need to sort it - the grouping works on unordered lists fine, the key for the group will ensure only same busses are in one group. Or do you mean for output-order when done?

Comment: I have the same issue with this as with L3viathan's solution. It does not merge my bus departures.

Comment: Well no, since with the list sorted it now works. You can also see in the method departures_model that all dicts will look the same.

Comment: It says here what i told you: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @AndersEkman  my bad, you are correct. never would have guessed. You still might want to `.strip()` the `name` in your model

Comment: @PatrickArtner No worries, I really think that the implementation of groupby is wierd like that. Anyway, I am happy with that it now works. Thanks for your help!
Strip just to be sure that it doesn´t diff?